# Loading Data into Table from Jquery in MVC

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have this Json returned from controller :

```
 public ActionResult VerifyApp(string recurrence)
        {
            List<foo> item = schedulingProxy.CheckApp(recurrence);

            return Json(item, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

And I have this table in my view:

```
<div class="table">
                <table id="thids" class="bg">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                Date
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Time
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Slot
                            </th>
                            <th>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach (var item in conflictList)
                        {
                            <tr id="@item.ID">
                                <td>   
                                  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ResourceFName)                             
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ResourceLName)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ResourceSlot)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.reason)
                                </td>
                            </tr>                                 
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

also i have added in the top of the view this :

```
@{
    var conflictList =new List<Mavi.Domain.Model.contactThread>();
}
```

And I have this Axaj call in my Jquery :

```
function ChkAvailable() {

        pairString = pairString + newObj.ToString() + "]";
        var requrl = '@Url.Action("VerifyAppointment", "Scheduling", null, Request.Url.Scheme, null)';
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: requrl,
            data: { recurrence: pairString },
            success: function (data) {
               //returned List<foo>
            }
        });
    }
```

How can i add the values from my returned JSon Object into the conflictList ?? Or better yet .. How can i populate my Table ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you right, you need just to append the new html content in to your table like this:

```
...
success: function (data) {
   for(var el in data)
   {
     $("#thids").find("tbody")
        .append($("<tr>").append($("<td>").text(el.ResourceFName))/*and so on*/);
   }               
}
...
```

Comment: Yup ... that's exactly what I am looking for.Trying it out now ... If it works you get the answer mark :)

Comment: It worked .. had to use $.each ,but other than that ... everything was a-ok.Thank you!